# When is 笛 read as もにか？

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, readings, names

I read that 笛 can be interpreted as もにか, I was wondering if that's only used for names and if that reading is common/would be understood? Or is it more of a "kirakira" name?

Thank you for your insight

Comment: I'm curious where you found this reading for this character.  According to my dictionary (角川の漢和中辞典), the readings for 笛 are ふえ, テキ, and ジャク.  Now in novels etc kanji can be given all sorts of different readings to suit the purpose of the work.

Comment: I've seen it as a name reading on a few websites, so I was curious if it was commonly known. I'm guessing if someone's name was written as 笛 it would be assumed to be a different reading such as ふえ？

Comment: 1978年の大河ドラマ 「黄金の日日」([wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E6%97%A5)) にそういう名前の登場人物が出ているようです．堺の豪商で敬虔なキリシタンの娘で本人もキリシタンという設定とのこと．笛とかいてモニカと読むのか洗礼名なのか見た限りでは判然としませんでした

Comment: あぁなるほどですね．情報ありがとうございます．

Answer (score 1):

It's not a common reading at all, and I knew no one whose name is 笛【モニカ】. If a real Japanese child had a name like this today, people would almost certainly call it a "kirakira name". But character names in fiction are often unique, and "kirakira name" is usually not used to describe such names, especially when the work is not set in modern Japan.